# How do I convert my HTML/CSS site to be used on Mobile/Tablet

Tags: mobile, tablet

I made a website in complete HTML/CSS and a little bit of Javascript and Flash. I would like to know if it is possible to have it be good for Mobile/Tablet.

I am working in Dreamweaver and i clicked FILE > CONVERT > XHTML MOBILE 1.0 but got this error message "couldt fix 4  elements without alt attribute.

If anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use response CSS.

[Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) is great for this sort of thing. [Divshot](http://www.divshot.com/) is a good tool for constructing user interfaces with Twitter Bootstrap.